# Is there a way to include type hints inside the clojure threading macro?

Tags: clojure

For example, as in the example [here](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E),

```
=> (-> "a b c " .toUpperCase (.replace "A" "X") (.split " ") first)
=> "X"
```

I'd like to be able to do something like

```
 => (-> ^String "a b c " .... etc etc
```

to avoid the reflection penalties, esp. in interfacing with java code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to type hint expressions using the `->` macro. While the following uses reflection:

```
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
(def s "1")
(-> s .toString)
;; Reflection warning, NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1 - reference to field toString can't be resolved.
;;= "1"
```

This doesn't:

```
(-> ^String s .toString)
;;= "1"
```

Maybe if you share a specific expression where you are finding it hard or impossible to type hint we can help you better.

There is a known situation where the type hint attached to the macro's `&form` expression is discarded, see this JIRA ticket [Macroexpansion discards &form metadata](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-865). Maybe this is what you are seeing?

Comment: With the expression `(-> ^java.awt.image.BufferedImage image
                      .getRaster
                      .getDataBuffer
                      ^java.awt.image.DataBufferInt
                      (.getData))` I get this reflection warning `reference to field getData on java.awt.image.DataBuffer can't be resolved.` Seems the first hint is adhered and the last one ignored? Are there any plans to fix this? The JIRA ticket is over 6 years old now.

Comment: @DavidOngaro The type hint in the case you shared seems to  misplaced, the following compiles without warnings `(-> ^java.awt.image.BufferedImage image .getRaster ^java.awt.image.DataBufferInt (.getDataBuffer) .getData)`.

Comment: @juan.faccoro interesting, seems I got confused about how `->` is expanded. On the other hand `(.. ^java.awt.image.BufferedImage image getRaster ^java.awt.image.DataBufferInt getDataBuffer getData)` doesn't work. Seems the `->` macro is able to preserve typehints while `..` isn't?

Comment: Looking at the implementation from `..` I think the difference with `->` is that the macro-expansion for `..` builds a brand new list (e.g. `(. ~x ~form)`) and it doesn't take into account the `:tag` metadata from the symbol that represents the method, whereas `->` explicitly keeps the metadata if the item is a `seq?` (check the source code [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L1680)).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

If you need to type-hint the initial argument to `->`, you can do it directly, either inside or outside the `->` form:

```
(-> ^String (foo) .toUpperCase)

(let [^String f (foo)]
  (-> f .toUpperCase))
```

There will be no reflection in either case.

If the value that you wish to type-hint arises at an intermediate step in the `->` chain, then you can type-hint it by putting the type hint on the `->` step:

```
;; note the type hints on identity and (identity)

(-> ^String (foo) .toUpperCase ^String identity .toLowerCase)

(-> ^String (foo) .toUpperCase ^String (identity). toLowerCase)
```

Again, there will be no reflection in either case.

(Tested at a 1.7.0-alpha5 REPL.)

Comment: This doesn't work for me, either in  1.5, 1.6 or the version you listed.  Will add the errors I saw to the initial posting for formatting /readability. Please see above

Comment: Got this working, thanks - your example assumes a function (foo) rather than a string, which I should've realized

Comment: Not a function, just something you can attach metadata to. `(foo)` is a list, `foo` is a symbol etc. (Macro-expansion-time types matter.) The version with the outer `let` allows you to type-hint literals; that's actually unnecessary, however, since Clojure is smart enough to notice that it's dealing with a literal value and just use the class of that (which is clearly immediately available). For example `(.toUpperCase "asdf")` is reflection-free, as is `(let [x "asdf"] (.toUpperCase x))`, while `(def x "asdf") (.toUpperCase x)` is not.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your case at least, there are no reflection penalties.

```
 user=> (set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
 true
 user=> (-> "a b c " .toUpperCase (.replace "A" "X") (.split " ") first)
 "X"
```

If you want to be even more sure:

```
 user=> (def i 23)
 #'user/i
 user=> (.toString i)
 Reflection warning, NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1 - reference to field toString can't be resolved.
 "23"
```

Comment: Thanks, but that was really just an example - especially in interfacing w/java code, there's a lot of  (.myMethodOnCustomObject (.myMethod object))  kind of stuff

Comment: @SteveB. Ok, I see. I would suggest to `(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)` in your `project.clj`. In general, Clojure would be able to detect some stuff and reflection won't be needed. In Leiningen, `:warn-on-reflection true`

Comment: Yes, thanks. I know how I can find the reflection warnings, I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to avoid the reflection